# Getting information from my controller into onclick confirm(alert)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i try to confirm a sale and i need sum information about the product..

**my View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Card</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber, "Serial No")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber, new { id = "sn" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber)
    </div>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="CardSale" id="btnSubmit"
        onclick="if (confirm('The owner dealer price is : **@Model.OwnerPrice** . Are you sure?')) { return true; } else { return false; }" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}
```

i tryed with the ' $.getJSON ' like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function ()
  {
        var serial = $("#sn");
        var price = "";
        var url = "";
        url = "@Url.Action("GetOwnerPrice","Card")/"+serial;

        $.getJSON(url,function(data)
        {   
            alert(data.Value);
        });
    });       
 });
```

and on the controller

```
 public ActionResult GetOwnerPrice(int sn)
    {
        var owner = db.Dealers.Single(s => s.DealerID == db.Dealers.Single(o => o.UserName == User.Identity.Name).OwnerDealerID);
        var ownerPrice = owner.ProductToSale.Single(pr => pr.ProductID == sn).SalePrice;

        return Json(ownerPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but i dont know how to return it to the onclick confirm msg or into my ViewModel..

any help?

Comment: `GetOWnerPrice` should be a `JsonAction` and not `ActionResult`. About the returning json, I'm not sure if it looks like what you're thinking since you're passing `SalePrice` to `ownerPrice`

Comment: 10x i will try it but it work before with actionresult.. now i dont know how to but this ownerprice in my vm or in the confirm messege (submit-onclick)

Comment: Why json?  Why not do a normal form post?  And what's up with the onclick="...?  That doesn't look legal to me.

Comment: That `onclick` is totally not supposed to be there...

Comment: because i want the alert before posting, if the dealer see that cost to him more that he sale it - he wold click cancel and we not post it..

Comment: you right i forgot a Unnecessary close tag.. /> =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way in which you have written it, the @Model.OwnerPrice value must be known during page generation, since the template engine only has values that exist in your model when it does the template-data merge.

If you *do* know this value during page load, then simply use the value in your model exactly as you have, and if the user ever gets to this dialog, they will see the proper value.

If the value of this confirmation dialog is not known during page load, then you have the right idea to retrieve it via an Ajax call. The trick is to update the DOM with the new information when the call finishes. You can do this in three steps. First, change your dialog box:

First:

```
if (confirm('The owner dealer price is : ' + ownerDealerPrice + '. Are you sure?'))
```

Second:
Declare a new global variable:

```
var ownerDealerPrice;
```

Third:
Get the price:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/GetOwnerPrice", type: "GET", data: "serial=" + serial })
.success(function (price) {ownerDealerPrice = price; }
});
```

Comment: I do the two first part but on the third i try to put it evryware but witout success.. maybee sumting like this :
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).submit(function () {
    var serial = $("#sn");
    alert(serial);
 
    $.ajax({ url: "/GetOwnerPrice", type: "GET", data: "sn=" +serial }).success(function (price) {ownerDealerPrice = price; });
   });
</script>
 
maybee you can pls be speciffic where writing this?

sory for my bad english =)

Comment: In this model, you would make the update call as soon as the price is knowable, perhaps after quantity changes. Another option is to make the call in the onclick handler of the button, as in:

onclick='$.ajax(...).success(function(price) { if (confirm(...) }

Answer (score 2):

finnaly i take the two answare =)

my view:

```
@model oCc.IPToGo.ViewModel.CardSaleViewModel

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Card Sale";
   var ownerDealerPrice = 0;
}

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Card</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber, "Serial No")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardModel.SerialNumber)
    </div>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="CardSale" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}           
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).submit(function() 
{
    var serial = "";
    serial = $("#CardModel_SerialNumber").val();
    var uurl = "";
    uurl = "@Url.Action("GetOwnerPrice","Card")/"+serial;

     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $.ajax({ async: false , url: uurl,  dataype : 'json', method : 'GET'})
    .success(function (price) {ownerDealerPrice = price; 

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true }); 
   });
 return (confirm('The owner dealer price is : ' + ownerDealerPrice + '. Are you sure?'))
});
```

the controller code

```
     public ActionResult GetOwnerPrice(string ID)
    {
        var currentDealer =  db.Dealers.Single(o => o.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        var owner = db.Dealers.Single(s => s.DealerID ==currentDealer.OwnerDealerID);
        var card = db.Cards.Single(s => s.SerialNumber == ID);
        var ownerPrice = owner.ProductToSale.Single(pr => pr.ProductID == card.ProductID).SalePrice;

        return Json(ownerPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **$.ajax** with **async = false**?
It will return control right into your click handler. Something like:

```
var tmp = 0;
$.ajax({ 
   async = false, 
   url = ..., 
   dataype = 'json',
   method = 'POST'})
   .complete(function(data) {
      tmp = data
   });
if(confirm("my message here: " + tmp)) {... }
```

Comment: on the "onclick" event? i try it but it dossent work for me.. 10x